# Run a python application/script on startup using Linux

Tags: python, linux

I've been learning Python for a project required for work.  We are starting up a new server that will be running linux, and need a python script to run that will monitor a folder and handle files when they are placed in the folder.

I have the python "app" working, but I'm having a hard time finding how to make this script run when the server is started.  I know it's something simple, but my linux knowledge falls short here.

Secondary question:  As I understand it I don't need to compile or install this application, basically just call the start script to run it.  Is that correct?

Comment: Depends on your Linux, but this is what init/upstart/systemd can do, or, more simply put a script in the [runlevel directory](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/run-levels-intro.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up the script to run via `cron`, configuring time as `@reboot`

With python scripts, you will not need to compile it. You might need to install it, depending on what assumptions your script makes about its environment.

Comment: To add some complexity, I actually have two that I need to run.  The second is more complex and consists of multiple python files and is more like an application.  Can you point me to some info on what I might need to do to install this?

Comment: Wow! A suprising and elegant solution!

Comment: @Jhorra check the [docs](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) and examples provided Actually you can have any number of crontab entries, running at any time

Comment: @Jhorra most of the times it is fairly straightforward - make an application directory, and run the main python script right out of there, e.g. `cd foo && python bar.py`